# Name resolution often fails on first attempt, then succeeds

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, connection

I have a network at home with a VDSL router + switch + wireless AP device (a ZTE H369A). On my network there are two computers: A laptop (running Lubuntu 17.04) and a desktop (running Mint 18.1). Both are connected by wireless. On my desktop, and just my desktop, I experience the following:

Whenever I try resolve the name of a host whose address has not recently been resolved - be it "directly" by `dig some.host.name` or when connecting to a site using my web browser - the first attempt fails with high probability (difficult to say exactly how high; but above 10% and below 90%). A second attempt almost-always, or always, works.

My generated `/etc/resolv.conf` says:

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home
```

My machine is running a `dnsmasq` instance - enabled by default by my Mint installation. Here's the command-line for that:

```
/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

and my DHCP lease file says it's the router-switch-AP box which also serves as my DHCP server. My current wireless NIC details (from `lshw`) are:

```
description: Wireless interface
product: AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
logical name: wlp5s0
version: 01
serial: ec:08:6b:1b:9b:68
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-79-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.2.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
resources: irq:19 memory:f7200000-f721ffff memory:f7220000-f722ffff
```

I have tried another wireless NIC from a different make and model, but to no avail.

What could cause this, and how can I resolve it?

(I'm guessing additional information might be helpful, but I'm not sure what specifically, so ask and I'll edit that in.)

Comment: `nameserver 127.0.1.1` indicates that your own computer (i.e. localhost) has DNS resolver software running. Find out what software it is, and what nameservers/forwarders (if any) it uses.

Comment: @grawity: It's just the dnsmasq installed by default in Mint 18.1. Added the command-line for it. If it has a log I don't know where to find it.